# How do I install Win 7 OS through bootable device?

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, reboot, dell-vostro

I Cannot install Win 7 OS in another PC which is Dell Vostro-1014 through USB bootable device. The windows installation shows a complete cent-per-cent, but then when it restarts I had to reinstall it time and again from the beginning. It will not get to the 'registry settings' or 'setup services' and would not 'prepare the desktop'. I've got into the BIOS, set the boot sequence to USB Hard Drive. How do I deal with this?

Thanking You in advance.

Comment: Why not take the USB drive out, or change the boot order, after initiating the reboot so that it doesn't attempt to boot from it anymore?

Comment: After the restart you have to boot the hard drive first in which you're installing the Windows. I think you should put the boot sequence in default order and select the USB manually from BIOS to install the OS. There must be an option for that. Mine is F2. This will fix the restart issue. Because it keeps booting up the USB when it should boot the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Techie007 and @Mohi for your valuable suggestions. I have just installed it a couple of minutes back after trying Nth times. And I'd love to share it with you. This is how I do it when the system says, "No bootable devices":
I checked into the boxes of USB HDD and Internal HDD in sequence from the BIOS setup. Now when it finished booting from USB and restarts automatically, I got into the BIOS set up again pressing F12 key (for Dell Vostro-1014) and I checked into Internal HDD only this time. And lo, it works perfect!

Thanking you guys once again.